# deleting a file using php codding and refer to same user/page

Tags: php

can you help me solve this problem? my coding have some problem here. I want to make a delete function where it can refer to the same page or same user after deleting a file. but the problem here, I can refer back to the same page and same user but the file does not get deleted.

```
<?
include('../connection/connection.php');
$showkp=$_GET['refer'];

$id=$_GET['refer'];
$buangdata=mysql_query("Delete from pelajar where kp ='$id'")
or die(mysql_error());

if($buangdata==TRUE)    
{
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert('Berjaya.');
    window.location="listpelajar.php?refer=<? echo $showkp;?>";
    </script>
    <?
}
else
{
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert('Gagal.');
    window.location="menupensyarah.php?refer=<? echo $showkp;?>";
    </script>
    <?
}

?>
<a href="delete.php?refer=<? echo $kp;?>" onclick="return confirmation()"> buang </a>
```

Comment: What is in `delete.php`?

Comment: this is the codding in delete.php. i link this page with listpelajar.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to use mysqli_* or PDO instead of mysql_ becuase its deprecated and not available in PHP 7.

Second, if you just want to redirect user than use header() instead of javascript becuase you can handle it with PHP to.

Here is the example that you can test.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ( "localhost", "root", "password if required", "DNAME" );

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
     echo $mysqli->connect_error;
    exit ();
} else {
    echo "db connected";

    if ($mysqli->query ("DELETE QUERY") 
{
      // echo $mysqli->affected_rows;
      header("Location: url.com?param=".$yourVar);
      exit;
    }
else{
  header("Location: otherurl.com?param=".$yourVar);
exit;
}
}
?>
```